# cloudflare install error on apache : httpd is needed by mod_cloudflare

Tags: apache, cloudflare

I tried to install mod_cloudflare on Apache.

but it says :

```
#  rpm -i mod_cloudflare-el6-x86_64.latest.rpm
mod_cloudflare-el6-x86_64.latest.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 8e5f9a5d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
httpd is needed by mod_cloudflare-1.2.0-1360806316.el6.x86_64
```

but I have apache installed :

```
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 16 2015 16:27:46
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.28.7 rev9999
```

How can I make it work?!

Answer (score 0):

have you install glibc
try `yum install glibc.i686` and try `rpm -i mod_cloudflare-el6-x86_64.latest.rpm` again. hope it works

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS:

```
# yum install libtool httpd-devel 
# wget https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare.c 
# apxs -a -i -c mod_cloudflare.c
```

Add the following line within the Webuzo Apache Configuration:

```
LoadModule cloudflare_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_cloudflare.so
```

Restart Apache.
mod_cloudflare is now working

You are probably better off following the manual installation guide on cloudflares site for mod_apache:
http://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads